# SQL Joining Based on Common Calculated Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2012. Querying data from two separate tables with non-overlapping key values. I was able to calculate a common key using `CASE` statements that takes the following form:

**Query #1:**

```
select 
   "Region" = case 
                 when Facility = 100 then Region = 'North'
                 when Facility = 200 then Region = 'South'
                 when Facility = 300 then Region = 'Midwest'
                 else Null 
              end, 
   Other_Variable_1, Other_Variable_2, ...
from 
   Data1
```

**Query #2:**

```
select 
   "Region" = case 
                 when Facility = 63 then Region = 'North'
                 when Facility = 67 then Region = 'South"
                 when Facility = 89 then Region = 'Midwest'
                 else Null 
              end, 
   Other_Variable_A, Other_Variable_A, ...
from 
   Data2
```

I tried to link the two queries by running a `JOIN` statement on the two `CASE` statements as follows:

```
select 
    a.Other_Variable_1, b.Other_Variable_B
from 
    Data1 a
inner join 
    Data2 b on (case
                   when a.Facility = 100 then Region = 'North'
                   when a.Facility = 200 then Region = 'South'
                   when a.Facility = 300 then Region = 'Midwest'
                   else Null 
                end) = (case
                           when b.Facility = 63 then Region = 'North'
                           when b.Facility = 67 then Region = 'South"
                           when b.Facility = 89 then Region = 'Midwest'
                           else Null 
                         end)
```

The query ran for over an hour before I gave up. Is there a better way to join the two case statements without publishing two separate tables and then running a third query?

Comment: I don't see any filtering going on in the query. Do those tables have a lot of records in them?

Comment: If SQL Server accepted your code, then I suppose the mismatched quotes in `'South"` were introduced purely for our amusement?

Comment: Try join two calculated tables instead of joining on calculated values. At least it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want extra tables. I just want to share my experience on the same case as yours. This method is more flexible that user can change mapping between Facility and Region. We have to join two tables (10 millions row) with computed value. We solve the performance issue by.

1.Add 1 "Region" column for each table
2.Every night there will be data processing that will update those columns base on specified value by user via MDS (I assume only user know the relation between facility and region)

```
create table Data1_Mapping_Facility_Region
(
    Facility int,
    Region nvarchar(60)
)
create index IX_Data1_Mapping_Facility_Region_Facility on Data1 (Facility) include (region)

create table Data2_Mapping_Facility_Region
(
    Facility int,
    Region nvarchar(60)
)
create index IX_Data2_Mapping_Facility_Region_Facility on Data2 (Facility) include (region)

insert into Data1_Mapping_Facility_Region values(100, 'North'), (200, 'South'), (300, 'Midwest')
insert into Data2_Mapping_Facility_Region values(63, 'North'), (67, 'South'), (89, 'Midwest')
```

Mapping_Data1_Facility_Region

```
100  'North'
200  'South'
300  'Midwest'
```

Mapping_Data2_Facility_Region

```
63   'North'
67   'South'
89   'Midwest'
```

Create index for Data1 and Data2

```
create index IX_Data1_Region on Data1 (Region) include (Other_Variable_1)
create index IX_Data2_Region on Data2 (Region) include (Other_Variable_B)
```

update Data1 and Data2

```
update  data
set     data.Region = map.Region
from    Data1 data
            inner join Data1_Mapping_Facility_Region map
            on data.Facility = map.Facility

update  data
set     data.Region = map.Region
from    Data2 data
            inner join Data2_Mapping_Facility_Region map
            on data.Facility = map.Facility
```

Change query to

```
select a.Other_Variable_1, b.Other_Variable_B
from   Data1 a
       inner join Data2 b on a.Region = b.Region
```

Compare query plan
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try to do it completely without the `CASE` statement and directly map the values onto each other:

```
select a.Other_Variable_1, b.Other_Variable_B
from Data1 a
inner join Data2 b
on (a.Facility = 100 and b.Facility = 63)
or (a.Facility = 200 and b.Facility = 67)
or (a.Facility = 300 and b.Facility = 89)
```

Next, make sure that no primary key is missing -- I have the feeling this is the case here. Otherwise you will get a cartesian product-like join of the data sets in your tables.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you claim makes this superior to the OP's approach?  And your warning about a "cartesian product-like join" surely bears more explanation.  Neither the original join nor yours is a Cartesian product.

Comment: @John Bollinger: regarding the performance, it is only a suggestion. I don't know what the optimizer is doing underneath so one should figure it out empirically. Still, more direct code is surely not a wrong way to go.

Comment: @John Bollinger: regarding the "cartesian join". When you forget an entry in a multi-key, one effectively obtains a cartesian join in a subdimension of the key (although I agree it is uncommon to call it like this, as all the world considers "cartesian product" as "join without condition" -- thus I wrote cartesian-product-*like*).

Comment: "Regarding the performance, it is only a suggestion" -- if this is a *guess* then it should be presented as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: tell me the principle of an answer which definitely proves that the performance on Nick's machine is improved. Moreover, I could also give some references to SQL books which definitely favor my choice, but it isn't worth the effort. Finally, the code doesn't fit into the comment.

Comment: I think this approach is quite good as long as the facility column is indexed.